# How to remove class using CSS

Tags: css

I need to remove classes from different elements within the `@media print` on my CSS and add those classes on the `@media screen`.

Is there anyway to remove classes from the CSS file?

Something like:

```
@media print{
    .element{/*Remove class*/}
}
@media screen{
    .element{/*Add class*/}
}
```

I need to remove `ui-tabs-hide` added by a jQuery function (which hides the element in a weird way, as its not `display:block` or `display:none`) class from those elements at the time of printing and putting it back when finished printing.

Comment: Why not try `:not` ... check http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.asp

Comment: @KingRider how will it help?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

No. CSS can't modify the DOM, only its presentation.

Comment: Include the CSS for all media in a stylesheet for media=all. Include the CSS for screen only in media=print. Include the CSS for print only in media=print.

Comment: What javascript will detect when is printing and when has finished printing?

Answer (score 6):

CSS can't take out elements from the HTML document, however you could try something like:

```
@media print{
element.relevantclass
   {
     display: none;
   }
```

This would tell the printed media to not display this element.

Comment: That won't work as the element its hidden using a class from jquery, I think it is ui-widget, therefore display:none or display:block will not affect to it.

Comment: @Cesar Lopez: So you need to remove the classes such that jQuery does not apply any function on them?

Comment: Yes I need to remove ui-widget class from those elements at the time of printing and putting it back when finished printing.

Answer (score 4):

you can use jQuery to do this.

```
$(<element>).removeClass() // or removeClass(<the class to be removed>)
$(<element>).addClass(<new class>)
```

if you want to do this on loading of the page, you can include this in the document ready function (as shown below)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(<element>).removeClass()
    $(<element>).addClass(<new class>)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

*This does not help the OP, but could be useful to others who end up here based on the title "How to remove class using CSS".*

Although it is not possible to remove the actual *class* from the DOM using CSS, [as mentioned by Quentin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4215432), in some cases it may be possible to remove the *styles* applied by the class, using e.g. [`revert`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/revert) or [`unset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unset) (possibly in combination with [`all:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/all)).

Here's an example that styles an anchor as a button on touch devices, but removes that style if a mouse is available:

```css
.button-anchor {
  /* example of a class that modifies many properties */
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  column-gap: 0.5em;
  background-color: steelblue;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}

@media (pointer: fine) {
  .button-anchor {
    all: revert;
  }
}
```

```html
<a class="button-anchor" href="">click me</a>
```

Note: use your browser's "responsive design mode" to toggle touch function.

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove a class using CSS but you can override the properties.